# Storing entity as property of another entity in GAE (Google App Engine)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
static void editItem(Entity item,Entity user)
    {
        item.setProperty("Owner",user); 
    }
```

Is doing the above thing of setting one entities property as another entity not a bad thing or I should just store the key like this -

```
item.setProperty("Owner",user.getKey());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google AppEngine docs:

> Properties of an embedded entity are not indexed and cannot be used in queries. **You can optionally associate a key with an embedded entity, but (unlike a full-fledged entity) the key is not required and, even if present, cannot be used to retrieve the entity.**

You can find more here in [Embedded Entities](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Embedded_Entities).

Comment: This has changed by now: _When an embedded entity is included in indexes, you can query on subproperties. If you exclude an embedded entity from indexing, then all subproperties are also excluded from indexing. You can optionally associate a key with an embedded entity, but (unlike a full-fledged entity) the key is not required and, even if present, cannot be used to retrieve the entity._
JFI for anyone reading this four years later.